# syntax error from code that is supposed to work

Tags: sql, syntax, sql-server-2008-r2

Why do I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'

from this SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_c_department_Test 
AS
    SELECT customer_id, department_name
    FROM tbl_c_department;
```

Comment: Not all databases support `create table as`.  Perhaps you really want a view?

Comment: I am really trying to copy a table from one server to another. So, I drop the destination table first and try to do a "create table as" to essentially copy the table.  Do you have any alternative code?   I am a SQL beginner :)

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: I am running Microsoft SQL 2008 R2. Should I upgrade to a later level server in order to support this syntax?

Comment: Just as a side note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: SQL Server has **never** supported this kind of syntax - you just cannot write this code, it's **not valid** in T-SQL. If the table doesn't exist yet - you can write `SELECT .... INTO (newtablename) WHERE .....` - if the table already exists, you need `INSERT INTO tblName (col1, col2, ..., colN) SELECT col1, col2, ...., colN FROM ..... `

Comment: Thank you marc_s :) Will I be able to do the above command in SQL 2017?

Comment: In this syntax, "SELECT .... INTO (newtablename) WHERE ....."  Where do you specify the FROM?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax in SQL Server is:

```
SELECT customer_id, department_name
INTO tbl_c_department_Test
FROM tbl_c_department;
```